# Why do I get such horrible WEI scores for graphics in my workstation?

Tags: windows-vista, workstation, windows-experience-index

[image: Asus P6t6 Workstaion]My workstation is made up of the following:

- Apevia Case   Asus p6t6 WS evolution
- Xeon w3540 quad core 8 threads 8m cache 4.80 gt/s 2.93GHZ
- 8GB Kingston 1333 OC
- 2 Visiontek Radeon GPU's HD7850 4gb total
- Hard drive 80gig 2.5 5400 RPM drive. (Waiting for my SSD)

My Windows Experience Index (WEI) score is terrible. Everything is barely breaking 5 and my graphics are a 4.0.

This is a fresh build and I made everything auto in the Bios. I guess it is an energy saver board, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it but if you can help me get my score up that'd be awesome.

I have a pc from 2007 that gets all 5.9s across the board so I don't know why a board that supports an i7 and Xeon would do so terrible in Vista.  I will be upgrading to Windows 7 also.

Comment: Is the Vista install fresh (from scratch) as well?  Are you using the latest drivers supplied by the manufacturers?

Comment: Are other performance benchmarks show similar results?  Have you double/triple-checked your assembly to ensure your cooling apparatuses are connected/functioning properly?

Comment: How do the cards actually perform in game?  Just because windows gives it a low score doesnt *actually* mean its performing poorly.

Comment: I'm not a gamer...I use the workstation for video rendering, photoshop, 3d animation, and music programs...but from what I can tell...they're great.

Answer (score 2):

There can be inherited results after you connect new hardware. You probably have done so already but worth noting to have all the latest drivers installed. Then clear out the previous WEI scores the following way:

Go to Start 
Type

> %SYSTEMROOT%\Performance\WinSat\DataStore

in the search area
Open the data store folder

Delete all .xml files

[image: xml]

Close and go rerun the rating.

Info for other methods are located at [Microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933478)

Remeber that Vista's max rating will be 5.9. Any comparision as far as WEI goes past that was measured with Windows 7 (not sure if 8 has WEI).

Comment: It gave me 5.9...totally suckish.  You'd think I would get well over a 5.9 with processor and those graphics cards since they are s'posed to be such high performing pieces.  I don't know why I can't break the 5's.  Everyone else I know with these cards are getting 7.9s.  I mean my computer is fast and haven't had a problem out of it...I just want the Windows Experience Index to reflect the computer's performance.  I don't think I should have to overclock my stuff to get these results I want.  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Well it looks like your score improved after refresh process? Doesn't Vista only goto 5.9? Windows 7 goes beyond to 7.9.

Comment: Yes....Vista only goes as high as 5.9. " The base scores currently range from 1 to 5.9. The Windows Experience Index is designed to accommodate advances in computer technology."  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-the-windows-experience-index